# How do I classify a dataframe in a specific case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, classification

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form. I'll show you a simple example.(In reality, it consists of hundreds of millions of rows of data.).
I want to change the number as the letter in column '2' changes. Numbers in the remaining columns (columns:1,3 ~) should not change.

```
df=

  index    1            2         3
    

    0      0           a100       1
    1      1.04        a100       2
    2      32          a100       3
    3      5.05        a105       4
    4      1.01        a105       5
    5      155         a105       6
    6      3155.26     a105       7
    7      354.12      a100       8
    8      5680.13     a100       9
    9      125.55      a100       10
    10     13.32       a100       11
    11     5656.33     a156       12
    12     456.61      a156       13
    13     23.52       a1235      14
    14     35.35       a1235      15
    15     350.20      a100       16
    16     30.         a100       17
    17     13.50       a100       18
    18     323.13      a231       19
    19     15.11       a1111      20
    20     11.22       a1111      21
```

Here is my expected result:

```
df=

  index    1           2       3
    

    0      0           0       1
    1      1.04        0       2
    2      32          0       3
    3      5.05        1       4
    4      1.01        1       5
    5      155         1       6
    6      3155.26     1       7
    7      354.12      2       8
    8      5680.13     2       9
    9      125.55      2       10
    10     13.32       2       11
    11     5656.33     3       12
    12     456.61      3       13
    13     23.52       4       14
    14     35.35       4       15
    15     350.20      5       16
    16     30          5       17
    17     13.50       5       18
    18     323.13      6       19
    19     15.11       7       20
    20     11.22       7       21
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use consecutive groups created by compare for not equal shifted values with cumulative sum and then subtract 1:

```
#if column is string '2'
df['2'] = df['2'].ne(df['2'].shift()).cumsum().sub(1)

#if column is number 2
df[2] = df[2].ne(df[2].shift()).cumsum().sub(1)
```

---

```
print (df)
    index        1  2   3
0       0     0.00  0   1
1       1     1.04  0   2
2       2    32.00  0   3
3       3     5.05  1   4
4       4     1.01  1   5
5       5   155.00  1   6
6       6  3155.26  1   7
7       7   354.12  2   8
8       8  5680.13  2   9
9       9   125.55  2  10
10     10    13.32  2  11
11     11  5656.33  3  12
12     12   456.61  3  13
13     13    23.52  4  14
14     14    35.35  4  15
15     15   350.20  5  16
16     16    30.00  5  17
17     17    13.50  5  18
18     18   323.13  6  19
19     19    15.11  7  20
20     20    11.22  7  21
```

Comment: OP's example output has rows 7-10 different than rows 0-2... - this looks like that consecutive groups recipe I know you know and can probably find a dupe of :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem. Have a nice day

Comment: @JonClements - looking for dupe.